# Is it compulsory for SVM to have two labels?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opencv, svm

I have a question regarding Support Vector Machine. Does SVM have to have two labels? Is it possible that there will be one label and prediction will be based on that label? For example, the following testData does not fit trainingData so it won't be labeled 1 but any other integer. The dilemma is that I do not know values for worst case scenario because all values are gotten from user input.

```
int labels[3] = {1, 1, 1};
cv::Mat labelsMat(3, 1, CV_32S, labels);

float trainingData[3][3] = { { 25, 191, 19 }, { 24, 186, 17}, { 25, 200, 19} };

float testData[3] = {70, 500, 100};
```

Comment: Did you look at the theory behind SVMs ? If not, I strongly advise you to read at least the introduction of the [Wikipedia page on SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) to understand why what you are trying to do doesn't make sense

Comment: Yes, I did. My application takes 3 inputs from user to generate some authentication pattern, so some third person can not access the information because his input data will be different. Those 3 trainingData above are success cases and testData is third person's input.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. There is just a fundamental problem with using SVM for this. How would you define a match between testData and trainingData ? Is it if testData belongs to the sphere defined by your three points ? Is it if testData's distance to your three original points is less than some threshold ? Your problem is fundamentally ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, testData's distance to my three original points is less than some threshold. And I want to define somehow this threshold. But do not know how

Comment: Really ? You don't know how to compute the distance between two points in 3D ?... And you want to use an SVM for that ?

Comment: I think you didnt understand me, I do not how to get the threshold. I read papers and most of them used SVM so I thought that I should use either.

Comment: Particularly, I am developing authentication for users. I collect 10 inputs from user and generate from that authentication key. And I do not really now how to use those inputs? Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

SVM is a classification method. By using SVM you can separate data into several parts and the labels requires for this. You should train SVM by more than one label then test it by new inputs.